# Cookie not save in foreach

Tags: php, cookies, cart

People
I am trying to build a shopping cart, So i will have to pass the id , quantity and location_id to the function. In the function, i will look at the id and location_id passed in, if similar id and location_id is found. I will +1 to the item. However, if i use the function in array, it is not working. 
Below is another function i built to test the variables pass to function within foreach. 
But is does not say the first variable i passed in. it will only save the latest variable.

Below is my function codes :

```
static public function test($id , $per_min, $location_id_cart = 0){

    echo $new_cart = $id.'-'.$per_min.'-'.$location_id_cart;
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cart_item'])){
        $last = $_COOKIE['cart_item'];
        $testing = $last.','.$new_cart;
    }else{
        $testing = $new_cart;
    }

    $set = setcookie("cart_item", $testing, time()+3600);
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
}
```

Below is my codes calling the function :

```
    $id = 125;
    $multi_location = array(636 , 789);
    $multi_quantity = array();
    $multi_quantity[636] = 5;
    $multi_quantity[789] = 10; 
    $array_key = array_keys($multi_quantity);
    foreach($array_key as $o){
        if(!in_array($o , $multi_location)){
            unset($multi_quantity[$o]);
        }
    }
    $count = 0;
    foreach($multi_location as $i){
        ZCart::test($id , $multi_quantity[$i], $i);
    }
```

My result :

```
 'cart_item' => string '125-10-789' (length=10)
```

My expected result :

```
'cart_item' => string '125-5-636,125-10-789'
```

if i refresh my page, the result i get is this :

```
'cart_item' => string '125-10-789,125-10-789,125-10-789,125-10-789,125-10-789,125-10-789,125-10-789'
```

The cookie will only save the latest value given in the array. it does not save 125-5-636 to the cookie.
Why? can anyone help me on this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```
static public function test($id , $per_min, $location_id_cart = 0){

    $new_cart = $id.'-'.$per_min.'-'.$location_id_cart;
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cart_item'])){
        $last = $_COOKIE['cart_item'];
        $testing = $last.','.$new_cart;
    }else{
        $testing = $new_cart;
    }

    $set = setcookie("cart_item", $testing, time()+3600);
    //This line deals with adding to the cookie while the script is running
    $_COOKIE['cart_item'] = $testing;

    //var_dump($_COOKIE);
}
```

I have a feeling that the `$_COOKIE` array isn't being updated when you use `setcookie()`, this is why we update it manually with the line below it.

Also I'd remove the `var_dump()` call, along with echoing the `$new_cart` variable, as this will stop `setcookie()` from working. Instead, I would put it at the bottom of your calling code:

```
$id = 125;
$multi_location = array(636 , 789);
$multi_quantity = array();
$multi_quantity[636] = 5;
$multi_quantity[789] = 10; 
$array_key = array_keys($multi_quantity);
foreach($array_key as $o){
    if(!in_array($o , $multi_location)){
        unset($multi_quantity[$o]);
    }
}
$count = 0;
foreach($multi_location as $i){
ZCart::test($id , $multi_quantity[$i], $i);
}

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

If you are implementing a shopping cart, I'd strongly recommend using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), which allow you to store the sensitive stuff on the server side away from harm and are in my experience much easier to work with than cookies!

Another option would be to store the user's cart in a database and then if they aren't logged in link to that cart with an ID stored in a cookie. This would allow the cart to stay around if the user closes their browser but keeps the secure stuff from the cookie. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: No problem :) do you understand why it wasn't working? I'm not the best at explanations!

Comment: yeah understand. In the first place, I wanted to do shopping cart with session, however after my website implement HTTPS all the session went wrong. therefore i am think cookie is safer than session for my website situation. sessions that are created in https are not able to access in http. tried methods from the net to solve it.. but none of them works.

Comment: OK good job :) the difficulty of stackoverflow is that I can't assume something, nor do I want to insult your intelligence! Have you tried looking at a PHP e-commerce solution's source code to take some hints? I'm fairly useless with e-commerce and HTTPS I'm afraid

Comment: Good luck with your project Kimberlee!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7644/discussion-between-kimberlee-and-darkzaelus)

Answer (score 0):

because you are not using array or different variable. Every time you call function in loop, It updates value of cart_item.It doesnot store value in different variables.

Comment: I want the result to be 125-5-636,125-10-789 inside the cookie.. therefore i didnt store the value in different variables. 

if(isset($_COOKIE['cart_item'])){
        $last = $_COOKIE['cart_item'];
        $testing = $last.','.$new_cart;
    }

if there is cookie exist.. i will take the cookie value and combine it with the latest value. But the problem is it does not save the first value of my array..

Comment: but if you store values in array with different index then also you can achieve your desired result..

you can use implode function to get your desired string in o/p

Comment: But i want to pass my $id, $multi_quantity[$i], $i one by one to the function. Because i am doing a shopping cart.. so by passing the items one by one i am able to identified which are the repeated stuff so that i can increase the quantity. I am giving my user checkbox and input text. They check the option, they want and enter the quantity in the input text.. this is why i need to foreach my array.